# How can I hide links in my react navigation drawer?

Tags: react-native, navigator, drawer

so I have a react navigation drawer, I can't manage to find out how to hide links in my drawer.
I have several  links to other screens but I don't want them all visible.
Here's my code :

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: drawer,
  Play: PlayScreen,
  Gall: Gallery,
  PlayerInput: PlayerInput,
  Cam: OpenCamera,
  srollView: ScrollView,
  Profil: Profil,
})
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.full}>
        <AppDrawerNavigator/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   full: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: '#458680',
   flexDirection:'column'
 },
});
```

Any idea ? thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following changes in your code:

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: drawer,
  Play: PlayScreen,
  Gall: Gallery,
  PlayerInput: PlayerInput,
  Cam: OpenCamera,
  srollView: ScrollView,
  Profil: Profil,
},
{
    contentComponent: DrawerContent,
}
)

const DrawerContent = (props) => (
  <View>
    <View
      style={{
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#458680',
      }}
    >
      //Your code here whatever you wanna display
    </View>
    <DrawerItems {...props} />
  </View>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can't display anything in the middle view in drawerContent, I juste added a text component to test but didn't display on screen, how can i fix this ?

Comment: Did you import DrawerItems from reactnavigation ?

Comment: Yes i did, thank for the rely, but I found my awser using "order: ['Home', 'Gall']"
This displays in the drawer only what's in the order's brackets